# JAVA JPA returning few Entity variables with their names using interface

Tags: java, json, jpa, interface, entity

Lets say I have a simple class:

```
public class Human{

private String id;
private String name;
priavte String surname;
priavte String something;
priavte String something2;

//geters setters

}
```

and I have declared an Interface

```
public interface IHuman{
String getId;
String getName;
}
```

in my repository I call:

```
@Query("select r from Human r")
Page<IHuman> getIdAndName();
```

Which in turn returns me an array of IHuman atributes with id and name, but when parsing to JSON it has no variable names and returns only the values:

```
"content":[["id1","jeff"],["id2","Jones"],...]
```

so my question would be: is it possible to connect variables to their corresponding values using interface, to get something like:

```
"content":[["id":"id1","name":"jeff"],["id":"id2","name":"Jones"],...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing

```
@Query("select r from Human r")
Page<IHuman> getIdAndName();
```

Which would return entire `Human` object.

But you only need id and name, so only retrieve that in the Query, like

```
@Query("select r.id, r.name from Human r")
Page<IHuman> getIdAndName();
```

And That should map your interface with your values.

Answer (score 0):

I legit don't know how/why this worked, but ok:
switched Query to:

```
 @Query("SELECT r.id as Id, r.name as Name from human r)
 Page<IHuman> getIdAndName();
```

and in my IHuman class I added:

```
@Value("#{target.Id}")
String getId();
@Value("#{target.Name}")
String getName();
```